# How to connect to a MariaDB database after collecting data about users and passwords with a SQLI?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, bash, mariadb

I'm trying to breach a dummy MariaDB database which is vulnerable to SQLI and is storing sensitive data about its users and their passwords. I've collected all the data I could collect, but now how am I supposed to connect to this database and tamper with it? I downloaded MySQL (MariaDB) and I was trying to connect to it by using Bash with this code:

```
mysql -h hostIPaddress -u username -D dbname -p
```

But I only get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on hostIPaddress`. What's the correct procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you can only connect from localhost/127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to tamper with the contents of that remote MariaDB database you will need to do it through the SQL injection.

Otherwise, if you are trying to connect to a locally-installed MariaDB instance you downloaded, you are probably connecting in the wrong way. Maybe the database server isn't running, or it needs to connect via a local socket rather than an ip address.